# Gitlab runner does not sync lfs object

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two gitlab runners. One of them is working fine, the other doesn't. It fails to sync lfs objects, and I can't find any reason for this. In my repo I have a zip file. But instead of synching the zip file, this is the content:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:21e6e15c57bd4c6d357090330f8199398cd702b609cbf268ee6da9e652dd5259
size 934583
```

The config file looks fine. Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if `git-lfs`/`git lfs` is not installed. Installing it should fix that issue.